# Understanding scanf() in C (Seg Fault)

Tags: c, input, segmentation-fault, scanf

I don't understand getting input in C. I have the following code which is producing a segmentation fault:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
 while (fgets(buffer, MAX_LEN + 1, input) != NULL) {
  get_command(t, buffer);
 }
return 0;
}
```

and

```
static void get_command(Table *t, char *command) {
    COMMAND command_name = 0;
    char *valid_args_str[] = {"aa","bb"};
    int arg_counter = 1;

 scanf("%s", command);

 if (!strncmp(command, "in", 2)) {
  command_name = INSERT;
  while(arg_counter){
   printf("whileloop reached, arg_counter is %d", arg_counter);
   scanf("%s", valid_args_str[arg_counter - 1]);
  }
.
.
.
}
```

The print statement isn't even being evaluated before i get a segmentation fault. Whats going on?

What is `while (fgets(buffer, MAX_LEN + 1, input) != NULL)`doing?
What is `scanf()` doing? Can I have one `scanf(`) follow by another? I intent for the arguments to be on the same line.

Thanks!

UPDATE:

Here is updated code. Still same problem. Hopefully this will be a more complete clip:

```
typedef enum { INSERT = 1, SEARCH, DELETE, RESET, DISPLAY} COMMAND;

static void get_command(Table *t, char *command) {
    COMMAND command_name = 0;
    char valid_args_str[] = {"aa","bb"};
    int arg_counter = 0;
    char other_buffer[MAX_LEN + 1];

    sscanf(command, "%s", other_buffer);

 if (!strncmp(other_buffer, "in", 2)) {
  command_name = INSERT;
  while(++arg_counter){
   printf("whileloop reached, arg_counter - 1 is %d\n", arg_counter - 1);
   scanf("%s", valid_args_str[arg_counter - 1]);
  }
 } else if (!strncmp(other_buffer, "se", 2)) {
.
.
.
execute_comm(t, command_name, valid_args_str);
}

static void execute_comm(Table *t, COMMAND command, char *args[]){
 switch(command){
 case INSERT:
  insert(t, args[0], args[1]);
  break;
.
.
}
```

and here is my main:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

 FILE *input;
 char buffer[MAX_LEN + 1];
 input = stdin;
 if(argc > 2){
  fprintf(stderr, "%s", "Too many arguments");
  perror("Too many arguments");
  exit(EX_OSERR);
 } else if (argc == 2){
  if ((input = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL) {
   fprintf(stderr, "%s", "error opening files");
   perror("error opening file");
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
 }

 while (fgets(buffer, MAX_LEN + 1, input) != NULL) {
  get_command(t, buffer);
 }
 fclose(input);
 return 0;
}
```

What I want to happen is for it to be able to read a file like this:

insert beans lima

delete beans

etc. and from standard input. Some commands have two arguments, some have one, and some none.

Thanks again

Comment: how is buffer declarated

Comment: You don't know that the `printf` statement is not being evaluated.  It prints on `stdin`, which is a buffered output file.  There's no sort of flush, and not even a `\n` which can trigger a flush.  Therefore, its output may very well be written out to a buffer, and is lost when the program crashes.  Use `fprintf(stderr, "while....` instead, as `stderr` is not buffered, and prints to whatever output there is immediately.

Comment: Also, is this the actual code you're having problems with?  I don't see `buffer` declared anywhere, or `MAX_LEN` for that matter.

Comment: Now, if you actually pasted the definition of `COMMAND`...

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your `buffer` variable is not allocated. Do you declare as such?

`char* buffer;`

If so, that is why you are seg faulting.

You need to allocate memory for the buffer.

`char buffer[1024];`

Answer (score 1):

`fgets` is reading an entire line (up to newline) from the file in variable `FILE* input`, and putting that line in `buffer`.

`scanf` is reading a sequence of non-whitespace from standard input, and writing that into `command`, which appears to be the same pointer as `buffer`.

Something here is almost certainly not what you intended.  Maybe you meant

```
sscanf(command, "%s", other_buffer);
```